# Looking to gain weight by putting on muscle

Tags: muscle, workout

I am very skinny and I am looking to put on weight by gaining muscle. I am 6 foot 2 and weigh about 160 pounds.
I am willing to change my diet. I eat quiet a lot of chocolate and crisps but not fast food. I am involved with a sports team and train 2 or 3 times a week but will be looking to hit the gym more.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? You seem to have identified your weak spots and got a plan what to do. Currently this question is far too broad and there are a lot of answers here that might help you.

Comment: Stop eating chocolate and crisps, start eating metric tons of real food, lift heavy, sleep like it's your job, and check out the link Kate posted. Should work.